# How can I add or subtract a number to a linked value through VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automate some copy-paste hustle and I need to do that by adding and subtracting updated numbers to the existing report.

But I should not break the links in the existing report, e.g. if the cell is `=link`, it should be `=link - value`.

I have tried using the `CStr` function but I still get the type mismatch error.

I also tried not using the `CStr` function i.e. directly adding or subtracting the values.

Pastes true values but breaks the links:

```
Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I50").Value = Workbooks("2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz").Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("E39").Value - OSmaas - TLmaas + TotPrim

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I55").Value = Workbooks("2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz").Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("E44").Value - TotPrim

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I50").Value = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" + ComboBox1.Value + "'!$E$39-I52-I51" + CStr(TotPrim)

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I55").Value = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" + ComboBox1.Value + "'!$E$43" - CStr(TotPrim)
```

The output should be values in the specified cells updating but I keep getting the type mismatch error.

P.S.: I tried removing the `+ CStr(TotPrim)` and `- CStr(TotPrim)` parts and the code works just fine.

Comment: If you keep getting type mismatch errors then you most probably try to add apples and pears, i.e. strings and numbers. VBA is extremely flexible in converting types (you can simply add doubles and integers) but there is no sense adding strings and numbers so first you'd better forget `CStr`. Make sure all variables including combobox.values are of some number type. You can enforce number conversion with `Val` though `Val("something")` will return 0 so it may lead to a false result.

Comment: If you want to add a formula to cell I50 and I55, use `.FormulaLocal` instead of `.Value`. In this case a `String` type is required, so `CStr` is fine. A `+` sign between strings means concatenation, however `-` as a string operator has no sense.

Comment: @AcsErno the .FormulaLocal worked man, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here some corrections that will make your code working:

- Instead of `.Value` you should use `.Formula` or `.FormulaLocal` if you want to use language specific formulas.
- In VBA **strings concatenation** use the `&` operator instead of `+`.
- Since it's a formula you have to include the operator inside your string, otherwise the parser will throw an error (instead of `"E3" - TotPrim`, use `"E3-" & TotPrim`).

With the applied corrections, your code should look like this:

```
Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I50").Value = Workbooks("2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz").Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("E39").Value - OSmaas - TLmaas + TotPrim

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I55").Value = Workbooks("2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz").Worksheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("E44").Value - TotPrim

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I50").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & ComboBox1.Value & "'!$E$39-I52-I51+" & CStr(TotPrim)

Sheets(ComboBox1.Value).Range("I55").FormulaLocal = "=+'\\ccfs1\Mali Isler\MIS\2019 Actual\Actual Navigator\[2019 Actual Nav - Temmuz Linksiz.xlsx]" & ComboBox1.Value & "'!$E$43-" & CStr(TotPrim)
```

> **Note**: I test this code (with different paths) on my Excel and it works.

Hope this helps.